# how to retrieve data from a Marklogic database when editing the generated source code?

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I want to edit the generated Marklogic source code by adding a select list for restricting search. The generated code is a javascript and the select list should contain information  retrieved from the database. I'm new to marklogic and i don't know how do so.

The generated code:

```
'<form name="query" id="query">'
    + '<input type="text" id="query-text" value="" autocomplete="off" />'
    + '<button type="submit" class="button" id="update- query">Search</button>'
    + '</form>'
    + '<div id="search-suggestions"></div>';
```

I want to add this code:

```
     <p>Choose a section: </p>
     <select name="sec-title" id="sec-title">
     <option value="all">all</option>
     {
     for $sec-title in fn:distinct-values(//a:sec-title/text())
     order by $sec-title
     return if($sec-title = xdmp:get-request-field("sec-title"))
     then <option value="{$sec-title}" selected="selected"> {$sec-title}  </option>
     else <option value="{$sec-title}"> {$sec-title} </option>
     }
     </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you used AppBuilder to make a sample application.

It should be noted that AppBuilder appears to be deprecated from ML8 onwards in preference of sample applications in Java and node.js.  For those, see github for [marklogic sample stack](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-samplestack).

**Extending AppBuilder Apps**
If you really want to move forward with extending the AppBuilder application, see [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-builder/custom).

**Export the original AppBuilder code to edit as you wish**
If you need to move forward with the AppBuilder code, I would suggest that you export the entire application's source code into a local directory and then use this as a base for your application. Then you just start editing as you wish.  For this, you would use [Roxy](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy)(the deployer part) and follow the great set of directions **[here](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2013/08/capturing-an-app-building-application-with-roxy/)** provided by [David Casel](http://blog.davidcassel.net/about/)